# Beginner in web scraping with python: When using BeautifulSoup and finding via class I either get the wrong class or the result "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to grab the UCI points from the following website: https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/tadej-pogacar

To start, I just want to grab the uci point from the latest race.

My code so far is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/tadej-pogacar")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "lxml")
result_date = soup.find("td", class_ = False, id = False, style = False).text
print(result_date)
uci = soup.find("td", class_ = "cu600 ")
print(uci)
```

When I run the code, I either get the class "gc cu600" or "None" depending if i search for "cu600" og "cu600 ".

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean that when you look for the class `"cu600"` you get the results you expect, but when you look for the class `"cu600 "` you don't?  It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: @David - The tag is originally called class="cu600 ". When I use this as my class I get the result "None". So I thought I'd try class_ = "cu600", but when I do this, I get "<td class="gc cu600"></td>" instead of something like "<td class="cu600">238</td>". I just can't seem to figure out why it is choosing another class than what I put in :/ So, I do not get the expected result either way.

Comment: Well, `"cu600 "` isn't really a valid class.  Classes are space-separated, so a single class name can't contain a space.  And when searching for the class `"cu600"`, I would fully expect it to match `<td class="gc cu600">` because that element has that class.  It sounds like perhaps this is just a misunderstanding on your part?  It wouldn't be looking for elements which have *only* that class, but any element which has that class at all.

Comment: @David - There is definitely a misunderstanding on my part. Does that mean class="gc cu600" are two classes?

Comment: Correct, `gc` and `cu600` would be two separate classes, and searching for elements of either one should match that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can get the `UCI Points`

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/tadej-pogacar"

df = pd.concat(pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="lxml"))
print(df["Points UCI"].dropna().to_string(index=False))
```

To get the points from the latest race, just change the last line to:

```
print(df["Points UCI"].iloc[0])
```

Output (all points):

```
   800
    85
   150
   125
    60
     3
   600
  1040
   210
   150
   150
   110
    20
    15
    30
   210
    40
   110
   110
   100
    50
   400
   500
   800
   260
   440
   500
    60
60 +10
   +10
60 +10
  2.86
   200
 20 +5
    +5
 20 +5
 20 +5
   125
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll look into using this approach. I just assumed you had to use BeautifulSoup for web scraping, as that is what I've seen on multiple courses :D But I'm happy there is other approaches to the problem, so thank you! Is this approach better in the case of tables as in the link?